# How to perform a health Check for an IBM MQ Publish operation in Mule

Tags: mule, ibm-mq, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a requirement where I need to perform a **healthCheck** for an IBM Publish operation. Currently we are posting all the messages with no issues. But, I'm looking for an other way to perform kind of healthcheck on the queue in case sometimes the queue is down.
I will be able to notify the source to stop sending message continuously.
Is there any kind of rest call where from Mule we can achieve this or any other work around to be considered.

Comment: A Mule connector may provide several operations. There is no IBM Publish  connector. Are you asking for the Publish operation of the IBM MQ connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform a publish in a transaction, and then rollback the transaction.  Use a Try scope with the `transactionalAction="ALWAYS_BEGIN"` and then raise a magic error to make it roll back.  That way the message does not actually become available to the consumers of the queue or topic.

Here is one way to do it:

```
    <flow name="healthcheckFlow">
        <try doc:name="Outside try to capture the error after the transaction is rolled back">
            <try doc:name="Inside try to provide the transaction" transactionalAction="ALWAYS_BEGIN">
              <ibm-mq:publish config-ref="IBM_MQ_Config" destination="importantQueue"/>
                <raise-error type="APP:ROLLBACK" description="this error is only raised to cause the transaction to roll back" />
                <error-handler>
                    <on-error-propagate logException="false" type="APP:ROLLBACK">
                        <logger level="DEBUG" message="Health check successful, rolling back transaction" category="example"/>
                    </on-error-propagate>
                </error-handler>
            </try>
            <error-handler >
                <on-error-continue logException="false" type="APP:ROLLBACK"/>
            </error-handler>
        </try>
        <logger level="INFO" message="Health check OK" category="example"/>
    </flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to implement a [Circuit Breaker pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern) for Mule 4. You could create a [Mule 4 module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/) to implement this pattern. You may be able to find some implementation but there is nothing official that I'm aware.